# Apache/php cannot access remote cifs/samba share

Tags: apache, permissions, samba

I am trying to understand what my problem might be here:

I am using a web application built on LAMP that needs access to a samba share that I've successfully mounted using

```
mount -t cifs ...
```

In the application, the samba share isn't accessible like other directories are. However, I can access it through the terminal just fine. Is this a permissions issue with Apache? If so, how would I grant permissions to apache from the remote computer?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried

```
//ip/foleder/ /mnt/name cifs  username=user,password=passwd,nounix,noserverino,defaults,users,auto,gid=33,uid=33  0 0
```

change gid and uid to the apache user
u can find it out like this:

```
 cat /etc/passwd | grep www-data
```